# Windows "type" command displays wrong space between numbers

Tags: batch-file, cmd, io, fortify

I'm trying to parse some summary report in batch script. (Summary created by "FPRUtility.bat" which is shipped with "HP Fortify SCA and Apps 4.10").
It has text like "*Total for all categories => 9 814 Issues*". But when i try to use this line in batch file (using type command, or passing this line to %var% and then using "echo") next text displays:

Total for all categories => 9┬а814 Issues

So as you can see space between numbers was changed to some symbols.

File encoding is UTF-8, if i change it to ANSI "┬а" becomes just "а".
If in any editor i delete space and type new space, then displaying is ok.
Turning on "Show all symbols" or "Show White Space and TAB" options in Notepad++ shows no extra symbols but space.

Comment: Try generating a hexdump and check what the byte(s) at that location in the file actually are. Unicode currently has [25 white space characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode), 17 of which are encoded using surrogates in UTF-8 (i.e. 2 bytes). My guess it's a non-breaking [en-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/En_%28typography%29) to avoid line-breaking the number in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [jrepl](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) (a batch/jscript hybrid script) to replace unicode characters.

```
FPRUtility.bat | jrepl "\u2013" " "
```

You need to replace `\u2013` to your *whitespace* unicode character